# Как сделать список из содержимого текстового файла?

Tags: python, list

Как сделать список из текстового файла, чтобы одно слово это был один элемент?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение для Python 3x:

```py
from pathlib import Path

words = [w for w in Path(filename).read_text(encoding="utf-8").replace("\n", " ").split()]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
file = open('test.txt', "r")#Открываем файл
all_words = []#Список со всеми словами
line = file.readline().split()#список из слов в строчке
while line:
    all_words.extend(line)#Вставляем в список с распаковкой
    line = file.readline().split()#Заново считываем
```

Вот так, "r" - вариант открытия для чтения.

Answer (score -2):

```py
F = open('')
lst = []
for i in F:
    lst.append(i)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]